# Minecraft Error: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Minecraft gives me this message in the crash report:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Sorry :(

Time: 23/1/15 8:28 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bss.an(SourceFile:526)
    at bss.ak(SourceFile:355)
    at bss.a(SourceFile:302)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bss.an(SourceFile:526)
    at bss.ak(SourceFile:355)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bss.a(SourceFile:302)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.8.1
    Operating System: Windows 7 (x86) version 6.1
    Java Version: 1.8.0_31, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 52381136 bytes (49 MB) / 101867520 bytes (97 MB) up to 518979584 bytes (494 MB)
    JVM Flags: 2 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx512M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.8.1
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: No
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
```

Comment: What kind of computer are you running this one? Minecraft is crashing because it can't find the video card. What make and model of video card does it have?

Answer (score 0):

What are your computer specs? If you are using Intel Series 4 chipset or earlier, you may not be able to run Minecraft on your computer. You can also try updating your video drivers. If that still doesn't work, you will either have to stick with Minecraft 1.7.2.

Comment: Arqade is not about getting hacked or cracked stuff, don't suggest getting them in your answers.

Comment: @TheCodingMonster Thank you for letting me know, I won't do it again.